# Using Skydrive api in android to get file list

Tags: java, android, onedrive

How to get list of files and folders from skydrive using SKYDRIVE API in android?

I want to know the java code and not the REST service.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great project on GitHub called [Live SDK for Android](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android) that will get you off on the right foot.

The [sample package](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android/tree/master/sample/src/com/microsoft/live/sample) contains valuable examples that should get you browsing files and folder quite quickly.